# ESP8266 AT+CWLAP does not return available networks

Tags: arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I am new to ESP8266. I try to connect ESP8266 to my network. On serial monitor I send AT and AT+CWMODE=1 command and I get "OK". Then I send AT+CWLAP command but it returns just OK. One of my tries it returned only one available network but it does not return every time. Most of time it returns just "OK". And it's not my network, it's my neighbour network. I didn't understand what the problem is. I'm asking for help

```
AT -> OK
AT+CWMODE=1 -> OK
AT+CWLAP -> OK (Sometimes only one network that is not mine)
```

Comment: esp8266 only works at 2.4 Ghz. It will not see a 5 GHz network

Comment: my network is 2.4 Ghz.